# Local file inclusion critical security issue

Tags: security

```
08/Jul/20 13:33:56  #5406089  CRITICAL     3  195.54.160.115   GET /index.php - Local file inclusion - [GET:fileName = /etc/passwd] - my-domain.com
```

I received this log in my NinjaFirewall plugin yesterday. Could somebody please tell me what this is? Google has found me nothing. Does this mean that I have a virus on my website?

Comment: If this is a message from NinjaFirewall plugin, then it makes sense to consult that plugin's documentation or support for help, and to contact them if that plugin is doing something that's not clear to you. It looks like this is an attempt at a Local File Inclusion exploit to try to get a local file. If your Wordpress installation is up to date then this should be nothing to worry about it. It's always a good time to check your Wordpress and plugins are all up to date though ;-) I found information by searching for `wordpress "local file inclusion"`